# Windows Explorer Navigation Bar in PyQt

Tags: pyqt, navbar

What's the best approach to mimic the Windows Explorer navigation bar in PyQt?. Perhaps a list of `QComboBox`es as part of a parent class that concatenates the current item of each combo box to resolve the final path?

Is it possible to get a similar look by using stylesheets?

This is the object I need to mimic. I just want a theoretical approach about the best way to mimic it.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to implement the functionality or imitate the design?

Comment: Do you want the edit box, as well, i.e. the line editor that appears when you click in a whitespace area outside the buttons?

Comment: Not really, im just looking for a way to split a path into fields and manage them on a handy way, so when i click on any of them i need to see the combo box behaviour to see the listed ites, in this case subdirs

Comment: I want tho know if it's possible to get that look using stylesheets on a combo box, and obviously, to know if it's the best way to try to mimic that object by using perhaps a Class that inherits from list which have on it childrends (added dinamically depending on an input argument, perhaps a path to be splitted into combo boxes), or pehaps there is a best way to try to approach to this. Perhaps you know some example of this on github. Im looking for an advice, your point of view about the best approach to this

Comment: PyQt4 or PyQt5?

Answer (score 1):

This is technically known as a [breadcrumb widget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation)).

There are multiple approaches to this. The closest emulation to Windows Explorer's behavior--leaving out the normally hidden line editor--involves a chain of widgets like so:

- A top level parent `QWidget`-derived class with your implementation, which would have:

  - A `QHBoxLayout`

    - An arbitrary number of `QComboBox`es
  - A `QFileSystemModel` from which to populate the combo boxes.

#### Alternatives

You could use a single `QLabel`s with a series of hyperlinks divided by path separators if you don't care about drop-down behavior. Qt Creator does this.

If your data source is static and not as gigantic as the filesystem, you could use `QToolButton`s backed by a tree of `QAction`/`QMenu`s. This is possibly a masochistic approach, given that you have to populate all of the actions and menus. Since that's what they are there for, though, it might be handy as part of a context-sensitive menubar or tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for such a widget too without any luck. So I've tried to implement this by myself. It's not finished yet and needs some more work, but here's the first result: [breadcrumbsaddressbar](https://github.com/Winand/breadcrumbsaddressbar).
[image: screenshot]
It's based on `QToolButton` widgets with menu. Parts of address which don't fit are hidden like in Windows Explorer. Also the widget has auto-completion feature.

Update: there's also a C++ widget [QtAddressBar](https://github.com/Longxr/QtAddressBar) which I have't tried.